# Translation Inner Join in JQL

Tags: mysql, jpa, jql

I have a problem with INNER JOIN in my JQL. What I want to do is to retrieve all Users that have rate one User Z with a mean of >= 2. Users have to answer 3 questions that will determine the final rate of this User Z. There is 2 tables, User and Score.

```
Table User    Table Score
Id_user       Id_score    Id_rated    Id_rater    Id_question    Score
1             1           1           3           1               1
2             2           1           3           2               0
3             3           1           3           3               1
              4           1           2           1               0
              5           1           2           2               0
              6           1           2           3               0
```

I want as a result only User 2 for example.
This is the error when I translare my query to JQL :

> [32, 184] The join association path is not a valid expression.

My query works well in MySQL Workbench

```
SELECT *
FROM User
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID_RATER, (AVG(Score.score)*5) as AvgScore
    FROM Score
    WHERE ID_RATED=1751 
    AND (
        SELECT (AVG(Score.score) * 3) 
        FROM Score)
    GROUP BY ID_RATER
) TabAvg
ON TabAvg.AvgScore >= 2
AND USER.ID=TabAvg.ID_RATER
```

Translating to JQL :

```
String sql = 
                    "SELECT U "
                    + "FROM User U "
                    + "INNER JOIN "
                    + "("
                        + "SELECT S.id_rater, (AVG(S.Score) * 3) AS AvgScore "
                        + "FROM Score S "
                        + "WHERE S.id_rated= :id_rated"
                        + "AND "
                        + "("
                            + "SELECT (AVG(S2.score) * 3) "
                            + "FROM Score S2"
                        + ") "
                        + "GROUP BY S.id_rater"
                    + ") TabAvg "
                    + "ON TabAvg.AvgScore >= 2 "
                    + "AND U.id_user = TabAvg.id_rater";
```

Comment: In JPQL you join across relations. You do not have a relation there. So it is an invalid query. This would be found in any JPA reference documentation

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't know what the problem with

> EntityManager.createQuery(sql)

but to bypass this, I used

> EntityManager.createNativeQuery(sql)

by just copy/paste my working sql into my code.